# How to get input from a user with ARGV in Ruby to read a file?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read the content of a file (myfile.txt) through ARGV in Ruby. Here is my code:

```
filename = ARGV.first

puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"

print txt.read
```

What I have to do to pass the name of the file to ARGV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

With a ruby script called `read_file.rb` :

```
# read_file.rb
# example :
# ruby read_file.rb some_file.txt
filename = ARGV.first

puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"

print File.read(filename)
```

You can call :

```
ruby read_file.rb myfile.txt
```

## Your code

```
print txt.read
```

`txt` isn't defined. If you meant `filename`, `filename` is a String which contains a filename. It's not a `File` object, so you cannot call `filename.read` directly.

Comment: Another option I found:                                                                                   filename = ARGV.first
txt_file = open(filename)
print txt_file.read

Answer (score 1):

Best use

```
ARGF.read
```

Notice the spelling with an `...F`

`ARGF` is a stream of either all files named in the arguments, or standard input if no file has been named. This is best practice for scripts and allows your program to be used with a unix pipe.

```
cat filename | ruby script.rb
ruby script.rb filename
```

Will both work and do the same if you use `ARGF`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
file = ARGV.first

file_name_with_extn = File.basename file        # => "abc.mp4"

file_extn = File.extname  file                  # => ".mp4"

file_name = File.basename file, extn            # => "abc"

file_path = File.dirname  file                  # => "/path/"
```